# how can i graph this function analytically? i can't properly use first derivative and second derivative helps me a bit but not enough

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

$y={\frac{x^3-4}{(x-1)^2}}$, so I have to graph this equation analytically, but when I use the first derivative to find the maximum, or minimum, I get the very bad cubic equation. so I can't properly find the intervals, where the function is increasing or decreasing etc.  but with second derivative I just find the point of inflection. so is there any good method to graph this equation.

Comment: The derivative does not have 'clean' roots, but you could maybe use partial fraction expansion to get $y=x+2+{3 \over x-1}- {3 \over (x-1)^2}$?

Comment: Please don't use tags you don't understand. :) I've removed the differential geometry tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

What you have is a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function). The first step to sketch such functions is to find the vertical asymptotes and horizontal asymptotes, if any.

The general procedure is outlined here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/alg/graphrationalfcns.aspx

This function can be written as
$$
f(x)=g(x)+\frac{3x-6}{(x-1)^2}=g(x)+\frac{3}{x-1}-\frac{3}{(x-1)^2}
$$
where $g(x)=x+2$.

Observe that
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)-g(x)=0,\quad \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)-g(x)=0
$$
and that
$$
\lim_{x\to 1-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1+}f(x)=-\infty.
$$

[image]

Comment: but how it behaves before -1 is kind of vague for me because i can't find local minimum or maximum

Comment: x+2 slant asymptote helps, but at (-2;0) interval it's kind of hard to behave. also, it's easy to find the intersection point between the slant asymptote and function. thanks for help

Comment: also how does inflection point help us?

Comment: @mathboy: in general, one is interested in *sketching* the graph to indicate its limiting behavior when one sketches it by hand. If the detailed structure of the graph is preferable, one would use a computer to plot it. If one wants to "prove" some properties of a function, one needs to do it in an ad hoc way.

Comment: thank you <3 good luck <3